# How to output more columns than input

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, xslt-1.0, openxml

Given this Open XML snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet5">
      <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="7" ss:ExpandedRowCount="4">
        <Column ss:Index="2" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="59.25"/>
        <Column ss:Index="5" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="75"/>
        <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="31.5"/>
      </Table>
    </Worksheet>

</Workbook>
```

...what XSLT 1.0 templating solution (avoiding loops if possible) can I use to produce this HTML output snippet:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:45pt;">
    <col style="width:59.25pt;">
    <col style="width:45pt;">
    <col style="width:45pt;">
    <col style="width:75pt;">
    <col style="width:31.5pt;">
    <col style="width:45pt;">
  </colgroup>
</table>
```

Note that the **ss:ExpandedColumnCount** attribute specifies the total number of columns. Also note that a **Column** tag in the source that does not include an **ss:Index** is a special case that specifies the next column index after the previous index; in this case, it evaluates to 6. All other columns assume the width of 45pt.

In my environment, there is no choice but to use the MSXML2 Engine.

This is just an arbitrary example of a range selection on an MS Excel worksheet encoded in Open XML, sometimes referred to as OOXML. I am looking for the XLST to perform this transformation in the general case.

Comment: Where did the value of `75pt` come from?

Comment: We need a fuller XML snippet to see where *ss* namespace is declared.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That's a typo. Fixed.

Comment: @Parfait The question is tagged [tag:openxml], but I've added to the snippet.

Comment: Technically speaking there are [no loops in XSLT](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tiploop/). Being a functional, declarative language variables in XSLT are immutable. But then you may point out the `xsl:for-each`, but this is more a mapping expression than a loop known in procedural languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done without an extension function, and in a single pass, but I might be wrong, as I haven't fully tested the following XSLT in all possible circumstances, but give it a go anyway...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ss">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="ss:Table">
    <table>
        <colgroup>
          <xsl:call-template name="Columns" />
        </colgroup>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Columns">
  <xsl:param name="MaxColumns" select="@ss:ExpandedColumnCount" />
  <xsl:param name="Column" select="ss:Column[1]" />
  <xsl:param name="ColumnNumber" select="1" />

  <xsl:if test="$ColumnNumber &lt;= $MaxColumns">
    <xsl:variable name="IsMatch" select="$Column/@ss:Index = $ColumnNumber or $Column[not(@ss:Index)]" />
    <xsl:variable name="width">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$IsMatch">
          <xsl:value-of select="$Column/@ss:Width" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>45</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>  
    <col style="width:{$width}pt;"></col>
    <xsl:call-template name="Columns">
      <xsl:with-param name="MaxColumns" select="$MaxColumns" />
      <xsl:with-param name="Column" select="$Column[not($IsMatch)]|$Column[$IsMatch]/following-sibling::ss:Column[1]" />
      <xsl:with-param name="ColumnNumber" select="$ColumnNumber + 1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This worked. And I like the fact that ti does not rely on an extension.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly you mean by "*avoiding loops if possible*". I certainly don't see how this can be accomplished without using *recursion*. In fact, I believe you need to use it in two places:

- first, to generate a list of overriding column widths where *every* node has an index value;
- then, to generate the required number of `col` elements.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
exclude-result-prefixes="ss"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="ss:Table">
    <xsl:variable name="col-widths-rtf">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ss:Column[1]" mode="col-widths"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <xsl:call-template name="colgroup">
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="@ss:ExpandedColumnCount"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="col-widths" select="exsl:node-set($col-widths-rtf)/width"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </colgroup>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ss:Column" mode="col-widths">
    <xsl:param name="last-index" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="index">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@ss:Index">
                <xsl:value-of select="@ss:Index"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$last-index + 1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <width index="{$index}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ss:Width"/>
    </width>
    <!-- sibling recursion -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::ss:Column[1]" mode="col-widths">
        <xsl:with-param name="last-index" select="$index"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="colgroup">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:param name="col-widths"/>
    <xsl:variable name="override" select="$col-widths[@index=$n]" />
    <xsl:variable name="width">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$override">
                <xsl:value-of select="$override"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>45</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>       
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="$n > 1">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="colgroup">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="col-widths" select="$col-widths"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <col style="width:{$width}pt;"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good answer! This recursive template call process looks similar to an answer you gave on my question in transposing the [Google Doodles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707512/xml-to-csv-transpose-by-dates). No doubt the @michael.hor257k signature!

Comment: Great answer, but as it stands it won't work for me. I am forced to use MSXML2 to do the transform and apparently it does not support the extension. Can your answer be reworked without extensions?

Comment: @astudent See if it supports the same function in `msxsl` namespace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz88kef0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Well, using the *msxsl* namespace it at least did not error during the transform, but it did not work correctly. All of the column tags were output with the default value.

Comment: Lack of error is not a sufficient indication of support - use `function-available('msxsl:node-set')` to make sure. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#function-function-available

Comment: Yep, it supports it, but it must be different because the output is.

Comment: @astudent If the function is supported, then it should work - so check your implementation. -- Yes, it can be done without using the extension function, by splitting the transformation into two stages and saving the interim result to a file to be processed by a second stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting your answer because I feel it will help others with a similar problem.

Comment: @astudent - reconsider this solution. While you are correct, MSXML does not support the *exslt* extension, you can still run an XSLT transformation with Windows' Powershell, thereby replacing MSXML using a VBA macro. See my answer below on the process. This XSLT has been tested on your posted XML in both MS Excel and MS Access using Powershell script to render the wanted, correct result.

Comment: @Parfait I remain convinced that replacing the EXSLT namespace with its `msxsl` counterpart should be all it takes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer again. In the end I preferred the simplicity of Tim's answer.

Comment: Actually, @michael.hor257k. You are absolutely right! Changing `exslt` to `msxsl` and its `node-set` reference worked with MSXML. Just tested it. I'm adding that to my library.